# An example of a topology on $\mathbf{R}^2$ in which addition is discontinuous and multiplication by a scalar is continuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

I am trying to build an example of a topology on $\mathbf{R}^2$ in which addition is discontinuous and multiplication by scalar is continuous. I think that such a topology is generated by the collection of all intervals on all straight lines passing through the origin $(0,0)$. Then, for example, adding points $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ gives a point $(0,2)$, but we will not have neighborhoods of points $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ whose sum is contained in a neighborhood of the point $(0,2)$.

But multiplication by a scalar in such a topology seems to me to be continuous, since for any neighborhood of the product $ax$ we can specify a corresponding neighborhood $x$ so that all points from it, when multiplied by $a$, fall into the neighborhood of $ax$. Namely, it seems to me that given an arbitrary neighborhood of $ax$ we can multiply by $1/a$ and get the necessary neighborhood of $x$. Can you please tell me if my reasoning is correct?

Comment: I've added some mathjax and rephrased a bit to make the question more readable, please correct if I've accidentally altered the intended meaning anywhere.

Comment: @ronno It seems to me that my example just won't work because of the discontinuity when multiplied by zero. After all, if my topology consists of lines passing through $(0,0)$, then for me the point $(0,0)$ itself will belong to the topology and be a neighborhood of zero. And for such a neighborhood, we will no longer be able to choose the neighborhood for the starting point and for zero so that the multiplication operation by zero is continuous.

Comment: It’s unclear to me whether you are requiring that for each $a$, scalar multiplication by $a$ is continuous, or whether scalar multiplication as a function $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is supposed to be continuous. But in either case I fail to see how the point $(0,0)$ or the scalar $0$ would cause any discontinuity.

Comment: @JonathanHole By definition, the continuity of multiplication by a scalar, if we take the element $x$ and multiply by the scalar $a$, then for any neighborhood A of the image $ax$ there must be neighborhoods B of the prototype $x$ and C of the scalar $a$ such that for any $x_1$ of B and $a_1$ of C the product $a_1x_1$ belongs to A.

Comment: @JonathanHole But in the topology I proposed, at point (0,0) there will be a neighborhood consisting only of this point itself (this neighborhood is obtained by the intersection of two straight lines), and for it we will not be able to find the necessary neighborhoods B and C, since in any neighborhood C we will have non-zero scalars, and in the vicinity B there will also be nonzero elements, so the product will not lie in the neighborhood consisting of the point (0,0)

Comment: Thanks, now I get it

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. Let $τ= \{B^c, ℝ^2-(0,0), ℝ^2, ∅ \}$, where $B^c$ is the complement of the unit open ball centered at $(0,0)$. It is clearly a topology on the plane.

I. Multiplication map $m$ is continuous. It is enough to verify that preimages of $B^c$ and $ℝ^2-(0,0)$ are open since those are the only non-trivial open sets and $m$ is onto.
$$
   \begin{align}
   m^{-1}(ℝ^2-(0,0)) & =\{(λ,x,y) : (λx, λy) ≠ (0,0) \}\\
    &=  \{(λ,x,y) : λ,x,y  ≠ 0 \} \\
    &= (ℝ-0)\times (ℝ^2 - (0,0))
    \end{align}
$$
which is open. Moreover
$$
\begin{align}
   m^{-1}(B^c) &= \{(λ,x,y) : ||(λx, λy)|| ≥ 1 \} \\
   &=  \{(λ,x,y) : λ≠0 \text{ and }||(x, y)|| ≥ 1/|λ| \} \\
   &= \bigcup_{λ≠0} \{(λ,x,y) : ||(x,y)||≥1/λ \} \\
   &= (ℝ-0) \times (ℝ^2-(0,0))
\end{align}
$$
which is again open.

II. Addition is not continuous. In fact it is not even sequentially continous: Let $x_n = (0,2)$ and $y_n = (0,-2)$ be the constatnt sequences in $(ℝ^2, τ)$. Both are convergent to any point in $B^c$,  in particular both sequences converge to $(2,2)$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
x_n \times y_n &\stackrel{τ \times τ}{\to} (2,2)\times(2,2)\\
+(x_n,y_n) = (0,0) &\stackrel{τ}{\not\to} +((2,2), (2,2)) =  (4,4).
\end{align}
$$
□

Note. There should be no trouble in generalizing this argument to $ℝ^n$.

---

By accident, I also wrote a sketch for an answer to the opposite question: An example of topology on $ℝ^2$ which has continuous addition and discontinuous multiplication. Since it might be of interest, here it is:

Consider the Sorgenfrey Plane (a product of two Sorgenfrey Lines).

A very similar task, but less technical, is to show that the Sorgenfrey Line, ($ℝ, τ_S$), topology generated by intervals $[a,b)$, has continuous addition, but discontinuous multiplication. The case for $(ℝ, τ_S)^2$ will be analogous.

I. Let $m\colon (ℝ, τ_E) \times (ℝ, τ_S) \to (ℝ, τ_S)$ be the multiplication map, where $τ_E$ is the Euclidean topology. This map is not even sequentially continuous. Indeed,
$$
\begin{align}
(-\frac{1}{n}, 1) &\stackrel{τ_E \times τ_S}{\to}  (0, 1)\\
m(-\frac{1}{n}, 1) = -\frac{1}{n} &\stackrel{τ_S}{\not\to}  0 = m(0,1),
\end{align}
$$
since $(-\frac{1}{n})$ does not converge in Sorgenfrey Line.

II. Addition map is continuous. Pick any $(x,y)$ and let $U$ be an arbitrary open neighborhood of $x+y$. There is $ε>0$ for which $[x+y, x+y+2ε) ⊂ U$. Then
$$
+([x, x+ε) \times [y, y+ε)) = [x+y, x+y+2ε) ⊂ U.
$$
We conclude that addition is continuous.
□